# Что такое функции в JS?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос по теории.

Все объекты наследуют от `Object.prototype`, ссылка на который храниться в конструкторе `Object()`. Конструктор Object - это функция. Но функция это объект типа Function, который находится ниже в иерархической цепочке наследований. Т.е. `Object()` является функцией, а функция является наследником `Object()`. Как так? Может функции и объекты Function это разные вещи, тогда это путает окончательно. Что является функцией, а что нет? А если учесть что в JS только функции создают свои области видимости и вообще контексты исполнения, то без четкого понимания что же такое "функция" получается просто мрак.

Comment: Функция в JavaScript это специальный тип объектов.

Comment: Не относитесь к выражению "в JavaScript все объект" как к истине. На уровне реализации языка это так, но пользоватей языка это почти никак не затрагивает. Есть искусственные ограничения, которые позволяют вводить новые типы, такие как функции, числа, массивы, объекты. И конечно они обладают своими особенностями, и все они являются объектами, но то что это объекты вас не должно волновать. Прочитайте подробнее про типы в JS, я думаю для Вас будет сюрпризом, как работают простые и ссылочные типы в JS. Прочитайте книгу по JavaScript, чтобы уложить информацию более последовательно.

Comment: Не так.........

Answer (score 1):

Не относитесь к выражению "в JavaScript все объект" как к истине. На уровне реализации языка это так, но пользоватей языка это почти никак не затрагивает. Есть искусственные ограничения, которые позволяют вводить новые типы, такие как функции, числа, массивы, объекты. И конечно они обладают своими особенностями, и все они являются объектами, но то что это объекты вас не должно волновать.

Прочитайте подробнее про типы в JS, я думаю для Вас будет сюрпризом, как работают простые и ссылочные типы в JS. Прочитайте книгу по JavaScript, чтобы уложить информацию более последовательно.

Comment: Я, конечно, все понимаю, но так нагло копировать комментарий другого человека... Слово в слово... Мдааа

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Человек не добавил свой комментарйи как ответ, отказался от возможных баллов репутации, вопрос до сих пор открыт, хотя ответ есть. Я его закрыл, никакой наглости. На эту тему недавно было обсуждение на мете

Comment: Да-да, правила есть правила и все такое, но все же сие не по-человечески

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ответы в данном случае, помимо репутации разместившему ответ, наносят ощутимую пользу в виде улучшения статистики отвеченных вопросов)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: и что нам с этой статистики? Изменились цифры в отчёте, который-то и не влияет ни на что, а по сути все осталось на своих местах

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, ну, это может быть очень полезно в привлечении новых участников - типа `Смотрите, у нас процент отвеченных больше, чем на en-SO`, приходите к нам, если хотите таки получить ответ на вопрос)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Дело не только в цифрах: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8646/Давайте-почистим-список-Без-Единого-Ответа Список неотвеченных вопросов многие просматривают, и вопросы с ответом в комментариях мешают. Только Dantessss упустил часть про "giving proper attribution to the ideas"